# Objects not showing in final render

Tags: rendering, objects

When I switch to render mode, they show up, and they show when pressing F12, but when clicking the 'Animation' button, nothing shows. If anyone knows how to help, please do.

Edit: I have enabled rendering using the cameras, still nothing.

Edit #2: What the, some how transferring all of the objects from layer 1-2 does the trick. I guess my camera was set up for the second layer even though it was physically in the 1st. Anyone like to explain?

For anyone who's really curious, [Here's the file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/wj78iv8hyjavjmd/NightmareFredbear2+%28WIP%29.blend):

Also, it may seem like having the animation length of 1 frame seem bad, but I've done that for other files and they work fine.

Comment: Did u mean objects not showing up in final render?

Comment: There are many possible reasons, please add a meaningful screenshot or the [blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to the question. Also see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33787/why-is-part-of-my-model-not-being-rendered,  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18884/cycles-final-render-pitch-black

Comment: Okay make sure then the object you are trying to render has render enabled. In the upper right hand part of the screen with all the objects, there should be a camera looking button next to the eye (hide or show). Did you try enabling that?

Comment: can you upload your file?

Comment: It *doesn't* matter on which layer camera is. It *does* matter which layer is set to be renderable in [*Render Layers* tab](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/post_process/layers.html). You can have camera on the 1st layer which is set unrenderable and have cube on 2nd renderable layer and the cube will be rendered. And it still could be easier if .blend file / at least screenshots were shown here

Comment: It's most likely a Render Layers issue as @MrZak has said. It would be great if you could post your blend file. You should not be getting different output between the F12 single frame render and the Animation render, as they should be using the same pipeline exactly. I'd be very interested to see why that was happening.

Comment: check your timeline (your animation length is 1 frame at the moment)

Comment: I confirm the problem comes from render layers : all objects on 1st layer, render only 2nd. I just don't understand why F12 render shows something else. I think Mr Zak should answer this :)

Answer (score 7):

There are two possible reasons for this happening.

### Reason I - Object Render Disable

---

You can disable specific objects from being rendered in the Outliner. It is possible you did this without knowing it.

[image: Outliner Panel]

The **Camera Button** to the right of the *Cube Object* is disabled, meaning the Cube will not be rendered. Click the camera button to turn on/off rendering.

### Reason II - Render Layer Settings

---

It could be that you have disabled the Render Layer(s) of your object in the render layers.

[image: render layer panel]

In the example photo, *Scene: layer 1* is **active** and will preview render in viewport, but since *Render: layer 1* is **not active**, then The objects in Layer 1 will not actually render.

More Render Layer Explanation -
The square buttons below 'Scene:' are the layers that are active and currently shown in 3D viewport. You have these correctly selected if you can see them in the 3D viewport and see them in the render preview.

The buttons below 'Layer:' are the layers that will be rendered. Select every layer that you have objects on to render.

The buttons below 'Mask:' will cause what ever objects on this layer to cut a transparent area through your render.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the camera and added a new one, everything became visible again.