# Meshes wont show up in render

Tags: rendering, mesh

So I've almost finished a huge project that I have spent hours upon hours creating and now I don't know what to do, I've looked up so many things to try and fix it but none worked

as you can see here I have a toy train

[image]

and when I render it you can see the carriages and they are just black and you cant see anything else and you can see the wheels have put holes in it or something but I don't know what I've done.

[image]

and an all my other layers when I render it there is nothing. Please help

Comment: See if it helps - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34809/objects-not-showing-in-final-render and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33787/why-is-part-of-my-model-not-being-rendered.

Comment: Are maybe the layer of those meshes selected in the render layers mask part? May it be that your meshes are accidentally emissive with the same color as the background? Do you see them in Cycles?

Comment: Are there lights in the scene?

Answer (score 0):

Bases on other questions, I think your problem is that you haven't enabled the meshes for render. At the top left, there should be a list of meshes. Click the camera next to the name of the mesh so that its like this:

[image]

And you should be fine. :) (Also, add some more lights to your scene so the meshes aren't black)

Comment: Nope, it already looked like that and the meshes are still invisible

Comment: If you upload your file it will be easier to find the problem!

Comment: What do you mean upload the file?