# Result of rendering is a black screen

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I have read a couple of answers on this topic, but they didn't helped me.
I have light and camera, but the result of rendering is always black. Rendered 3D-view is OK, but in Material view my model is black. What shall I do?

[image]

Comment: is it black after pressing F12, or in the 3d view?

Comment: After pressing F12

Comment: Do you use cycles or Blender internal rendering?

Comment: I use internal, but in cycles it doesn't render too.

Comment: Consider uploading your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and post the given link in your question.

Comment: The object is set to be not renderable (but visible in 3d viewport hence it's visible in preview render). See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/964/object-not-visible-in-render

Comment: Also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34809/objects-not-showing-in-final-render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have turned off rendering of the text objects. In the outliner, click on the greyed out camera icons next to the names of the text objects, to activate.

[image]
[image]

Now it should render just fine.
[image]