# Doing a Green Screen composite renders black

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, video

I am a newbie to composite editing, and I followed this green screen tutorial
on youtube: [Blender Video Editing - Part 13 (Green Screen compositing)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZzmksnzrX0).

I have audio in the VSE synced up also. I have the start frame and end frame starting at a different place (other than frame 1) to cut out unwanted footage. Everything looks great in the Composite Viewer but for some reason it renders black.
[image: composite nodes]
[image: rest of the composite nodes]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The way to trouble shoot what is happening is plugging the viewer node to each of the nodes of the chain, one by one, to find where things are not going right. Other useful tool is **muting** the nodes (press M) and see if  the effect of a particular node is throwing things off.

Comment: I plugged the viewer into each node as well and everything looks as expected.

Comment: ok last guess (after this I would ask that you export a frame from your movie as a png use that as your footage and upload the blend) do you have more then one *Composite* node in your nodes?

Comment: on the post processing section uncheck sequencer

Comment: Very cool! Thanks Cegaton! It was just because of having the sequencer checked in post processing. I rendered and all was fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cycles final render pitch black?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18884/cycles-final-render-pitch-black) and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering/5286#5286