# Blender Rendering in F12, But Not in Final Render

Tags: rendering, osx

As the title said, I am working on rendering objects in Blender 2.76b on Mac OSX. In F12, the objects render properly, however, they do not show up in the final render. Ideas? This is for a performance that is coming up soon, any help would be appreciated.
ALSO:
Yes, we checked for hidden objects. None hidden.
No, the issue isn't that objects are overlapping- We have put them on different layers, it didn't help.
Lamps are irrelevant, they are all emission objects.
This is in Cycles Render.
All layers are active.
To clarify, when I pressed F12 the image would come out fine. However, when the final render went through, there was only black.
EDIT:
Good news, for some reason we had to move the entire piece to another scene, for some reason.

Comment: Try unchecking the sequencer box in post processing. see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18895/1853

Comment: Cycles or Internal? Are you using the compostitor? Can you post images of your render settings?

Comment: Could you clarify as for what do you mean "final render" ? The `F12` shortcut invokes final rendering of the image with compositing nodes and / or sequencer clips applied (if any). How does your situation differ ?

Comment: Since we are all shooting in the dark here, here are some thoughts, make sure All layers are active '[` / ~] Key' (Jest to the left of the '1' key on the qwerty NOT the numpad), make sure that you don't have any mask layers active in your layer tab under any render layer, make sure all of your render layer entries are checked (The List of named Render Layers in the top part of the panel), and make sure none of your normals are flipped.